# Several specific methods or one generic method?

Tags: c++

this is my first question after long time checking on this marvelous webpage.

Probably my question is a little silly but I want to know others opinion about this. What is better, to create several specific methods or, on the other hand, only one generic method? Here is an example...

```
unsigned char *Method1(CommandTypeEnum command, ParamsCommand1Struct *params)
{
if(params == NULL) return NULL;

// Construct a string (command) with those specific params (params->element1, ...)

return buffer; // buffer is a member of the class 
}

unsigned char *Method2(CommandTypeEnum command, ParamsCommand2Struct *params)
{
...
}

unsigned char *Method3(CommandTypeEnum command, ParamsCommand3Struct *params)
{
...
}
unsigned char *Method4(CommandTypeEnum command, ParamsCommand4Struct *params)
{
...
}
```

or

```
unsigned char *Method(CommandTypeEnum command, void *params)
{
switch(command)
{
case CMD_1:
{
if(params == NULL) return NULL;

ParamsCommand1Struct *value = (ParamsCommand1Struct *) params;

// Construct a string (command) with those specific params (params->element1, ...)

return buffer;
}
break;

// ...

default:
break;
}
}
```

The main thing I do not really like of the latter option is this,

```
ParamsCommand1Struct *value = (ParamsCommand1Struct *) params;
```

because "params" could not be a pointer to "ParamsCommand1Struct" but a pointer to "ParamsCommand2Struct" or someone else.

I really appreciate your opinions!

Comment: Are you using C or C++? The answers will vary depending on which of these you are actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General Answer**

In [*Writing Solid Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556155514), Steve Macguire's advice is to prefer distinct functions (methods) for specific situations.  The reason is that you can assert conditions that are relevant to the specific case, and you can more easily debug because you have more context.

An interesting example is the standard C run-time's functions for dynamic memory allocation.  Most of it is redundant, as `realloc` can actually do (almost) everything you need.  If you have `realloc`, you don't need `malloc` or `free`.  But when you have such a general function, used for several different types of operations, it's hard to add useful assertions and it's harder to write unit tests, and it's harder to see what's happening when debugging.  Macquire takes it a step farther and suggests that, not only should `realloc` just do _re_allocation, but it should probably be two distinct functions:  one for growing a block and one for shrinking a block.

While I generally agree with his logic, *sometimes* there are practical advantages to having one general purpose method (often when operations is highly data-driven).  So I usually decide on a case by case basis, with a bias toward creating very specific methods rather than overly general purpose ones.

**Specific Answer**

In your case, I think you need to find a way to factor out the common code from the specifics.  The `switch` is often a signal that you should be using a small class hierarchy with virtual functions.

If you like the single method approach, then it probably should be just a dispatcher to the more specific methods.  In other words, each of those cases in the switch statement simply call the appropriate `Method1`, `Method2`, etc.  If you want the user to see only the general purpose method, then you can make the specific implementations private methods.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's better to offer separate functions, because they by their prototype names and arguments communicate directly and visibly to the user that which is available; this also leads to more straightforward documentation.

The one time I use a multi-purpose function is for something like a query() function, where a number of minor query functions, rather than leading to a proliferation of functions, are bundled into one, with a generic input and output void pointer.

In general, think about what you're trying to communicate to the API user *by the API prototypes themselves*; a clear sense of what the API can do.  He doesn't need excessive minutae; he does need to know the core functions which are the entire point of having the API in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to decide which language you are using.  Tagging the question with both `C` and `C++` here makes no sense.  I am assuming C++.

If you *can* create a generic function then of course that is preferable (why would you prefer multiple, redundant functions?)  The question is; can you?  However, you seem to be unaware of templates.  We need to see what you have omitted here to tell if you if templates are suitable however:

> // Construct a string (command) with those specific params (params->element1, ...)

In the general case, assuming templates are appropriate, all of that turns into:

```
template <typename T>
unsigned char *Method(CommandTypeEnum command, T *params) {
    // more here
}
```

---

On a side note, how is `buffer` declared?  Are you returning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory?  Prefer RAII type objects and avoid dynamically allocating memory like that if so.

Comment: In this case, buffer is a member of the Class. This is aimed for an embedded system so we try to avoid dynamically allocating memory...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ then I would avoid using void* as you don't really need to. There is nothing wrong with having multiple methods. Note that you don't actually have to rename the function in your first set of examples - you can just overload a function using different parameters so that there is a separate function signature for each type. Ultimately, this kind of question is very subjective and there are a number of ways of doing things. Looking at your functions of the first type, you would perhaps be well served by looking into the use of templated functions

Answer (score 0):

You could create a struct. That's what I use to handle console commands.

```
typedef int       (* pFunPrintf)(const char*,...);
typedef void      (CommandClass::*pKeyFunc)(char *,pFunPrintf);

struct KeyCommand
{
    const char * cmd;
    unsigned char cmdLen;
    pKeyFunc pfun;
    const char * Note;
    long ID;
};

#define CMD_FORMAT(a) a,(sizeof(a)-1)
static KeyCommand Commands[]=
{
    {CMD_FORMAT("one"),            &CommandClass::CommandOne,               "String Parameter",0},
    {CMD_FORMAT("two"),            &CommandClass::CommandTwo,               "String Parameter",1},
    {CMD_FORMAT("three"),          &CommandClass::CommandThree,             "String Parameter",2},
    {CMD_FORMAT("four"),           &CommandClass::CommandFour,              "String Parameter",3},

}; 

#define  AllCommands sizeof(Commands)/sizeof(KeyCommand)
```

And the Parser function

```
void CommandClass::ParseCmd( char* Argcommand )
 {
            unsigned int x;
            for ( x=0;x<AllCommands;x++)
            {
                if(!memcmp(Commands[x].cmd,Argcommand,Commands[x].cmdLen ))
                {
                    (this->*Commands[x].pfun)(&Argcommand[Commands[x].cmdLen],&::printf);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(x==AllCommands)
            {
                // Unknown command
            }

}
```

I use a thread safe printf pPrintf, so ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want to do, but in C++ you probably should derive multiple classes from a Formatter Base class like this:

```
class Formatter
{
    virtual void Format(unsigned char* buffer, Command command) const = 0;
};

class YourClass
{
public:
    void Method(Command command, const Formatter& formatter)
    {
        formatter.Format(buffer, command);
    }

private:
    unsigned char* buffer_;
};

int main()
{
    //
    Params1Formatter formatter(/*...*/);
    YourClass yourObject;

    yourObject.Method(CommandA, formatter);
    // ...
}
```

This removes the resposibility to handle all that params stuff from your class and makes it [closed for changes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). If there will be new commands or parameters during further development you don't have to modifiy (and eventually break) existing code but add new classes that implement the new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

While not full answer this should guide you in correct direction: ONE FUNCTION ONE RESPONSIBILITY. Prefer the code where it is responsible for one thing only and does it well. The code whith huge switch statement (which is not bad by itself) where you need cast void * to some other type is a smell.

By the way I hope you do realise that according to standard you can only cast from void * to <type> * only when the original cast was exactly from <type> * to void *.